# return a shared Observable from a service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables

How can I return a shared observable from a services' method?
I want to get only one call to the request and share it between subscribers.
I can get the expected result if I assign the method to a public field but then I cannot pass a param to it.

here is the service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FetchService {
  private entries$ = new Subject<number>();

  constructor() {}

  refreshEntries(id: number) {
    this.entries$.next(id);
  }

  getEntries(id = 0) {
    return this.entries$.pipe(
      startWith(id),
      mergeMap((id) => this.requestEntries(id)),
      shareReplay(1), 
    );
  }

  requestEntries(id: number) {
    console.log('requestEntries');
    return of([1, 2, 3]);
  }
}
```

and the call:

```
this.entries$ = this.service.getEntries(0); // called with async pipe in template
this.service.getEntries(0).subscribe((entries) => console.log(entries));
```

I want the `console.log('requestEntries')` to be called once.

it works if I make it without the getEntries method but then I can pass the id to the call.
I've omitted the code with the id for now, as it returns some cached data.
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-smyalx?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
export class FetchService {
  private entries: Observable<number[]>[] = [];

  constructor() {}

  refreshEntries(id: number) {
    this.entries[id] = of([1, 2, 3]).pipe(shareReplay(1));
  }

  getEntries(id = 0) {
    if(!this.entries[id]){
      this.entries[id] = of([1, 2, 3]).pipe(shareReplay(1));
    }
    return this.entries[id];
  }
}
```

This simply creates a shared observable and puts it in a list. It keeps returning this observable until it is refreshed.

Comment: Thank you, this pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to build some kind of service cache, right?

It can be achieved in a different way with Angular, but speaking of your particular request, it can be done this way ([demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-en1sfu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fservice%2Ffetch.service.ts))

```
type CacheKey = number;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FetchService {
  private cache: Record<CacheKey, Observable<any>> = {};
  constructor() {}

  refreshEntries(id: number) {
    this.removeCache(id);
  }

  getEntries(id = 0) {
    return this.getOrCreate(id);
  }

  requestEntries(id: number) {
    console.log('requestEntries');
    return of([1, 2, 3]);
  }

  private getOrCreate(id: CacheKey) {
    if (this.cache[id] === undefined) {
      this.cache[id] = this.requestEntries(id).pipe(shareReplay(1));
    }

    return this.cache[id];
  }

  private removeCache(id: CacheKey) {
    delete this.cache[id];
  }
```

Comment: Thank you with @RobinDijkhofs answer I got to a kinda same implementation as what you suggested. With a Map instead of Record